# List of values as a user attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using identity 2.1.0 in ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and I have pages for admin to work (create/edit/delete user) with some custom user properties I defined. However I need to store a list of values in one field. How can I achieve this by using identity, and how to show this on a web page ?

Comment: `However I need to store a list of values in one field.` - Why? Can you give an example? Its hard to help without knowing what you actually want to do...

Comment: I have a user with a custom property countries. I this property I want to store one or more countries, so that I can filter web page based on its selection of countries.

Comment: Thats a `n:m` relationship and shouldn't be saved "in one field" - I'll write you an answer with an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save such values you can extend your `ApplicationUser`, in case of multiple values you can do this via an `n:m` relationship:

First create a table to store the country values in (also add to your `DbContext` as e.g. `public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }`):

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } // or e.g. "string Code" to save e.g. "us"

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUsers> Users { get; set; }
}
```

then you can also add a list of `Country` to your `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<KEY>
{
     // ...

     public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

and finally to update the countries of a user something like the following:

```
var user = // get user
var countryToAdd = db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == countryName) ??
                       new Country() { Name = countryName };
if (user.Countries == null)
    user.Countries = new List<Country>() { countryToAdd };
else if (!user.Countries.Contains(countryToAdd))
    user.Countries.Add(countryToAdd);

db.SaveChanges();
```

And to get all users from one country:

```
var country = db.Countries.Include(c => c.Users)
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == countryName);
if (country != null)
{
    var users = country.Users;
}
```